# How to select multiple variables from dataframe and store it in a new dataframe

Tags: r

I searched and found this solution, which is what i want but it does not work like it should.  I have 81 variables and 114,000 observations. I want to pick only 25 variables from this dataframe (loanData).  By using

```
LoanVars <- select.list(names(loanData),multiple=TRUE,
                title='select your variable names',
                graphics=TRUE)
```

I was able to pick all variables that I want to keep and store it in the LoanVars.  I thought this is the new dataframe I will work with.  But it's not.  it created error when i try to summary(LoanVars) as it did not provide the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `select_` function from `dplyr`.

Here's an example using the iris data set for reproducibility.

```
library(dplyr)
selection = select.list(names(iris), multiple = T)
choice = iris %>% select_(.dots = selection)
```

Comment: I try but it produces error: Invalid input, please try again
But thank you so much for replying.  This is my first time asking question and i am very excited that I got you to review it.

Comment: Post your code and the error in detail, otherwise there is no chance of being able to determine the problem.

Comment: The line after the `select.list` is being interpreted as the selection. This happens if you run all the lines at once. If you run them one by one, the error does not happen.